# jqGrid - how to search when using datatype:local Or loadonce: true

Tags: search, jqgrid, local

I have a problem with jqGrid when I'm using the options specified. Seems that nothing happens when I click 'Find'. 
From jqGrid documentation I understand that sorting and searching is done locally when using loadonce option. Sorting is fine but search not, should it work locally or just server side, if so how to do that?

Thanks
Ovidiu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>According to the [Search Configuration](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config) section of the jqGrid documentation:</strike>

> Currently we do not have module for searching on local data i.e when a datatype options is set to local. All the searching is done server side.

So you will need to implement search using a server-side data source. You should be able to follow the examples on the jqGrid site to put at least a first-cut of this together.

**Update**

As of 3.7, jqGrid now supports local searching of data. Please see the same link at [Search Configuration](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:search_config) and the [jqGrid Demos](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) under the section `New in version 3.7` for more information.